# How can I merge contents of 2 cells into 1 and shift the remaining columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, merge, cell

I'm trying to merge cells in excel that are in the same row into 1 cell and then shift the remaining cells to the left.

Example:

Content  |  Sample  |  More  |  More2

So I want to merge "Content" and "Sample" and shift "More" and "More2" cells to the left so the result would be.

Content Sample  |  More  |  More2

I found a code that merges the 2 columns but it merges the 2 columns into 1 but it still takes up the second columns. So I have to "Unmerge" and delete the second column and shift "More" and "More2" to the left.

Heres the code that I have:

```
    Sub MergeOneCell()
    'Updateby20140128
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Sigh As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Sigh = Application.InputBox("Symbol merge", xTitleId, ",", Type:=2)
    xOut = ""
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xOut = xOut & Rng.Value & Sigh
    Next
    With WorkRng
    .Merge
    .Value = VBA.Left(xOut, VBA.Len(xOut) - 1)
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a ton of data to process and being able to make this happen would save me hours. I just haven't found any solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop through the data like so

```
'Find the last row of data
finalRow = cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row
for i = 1 to finalRow
  cells(i,1) = cells(i,1) & " " & cells(i,2)
  cells(i,2) = cells(i,3)
  cells(i,3) = cells(i,4)
next i
```

This assumes `Content | Sample | More | More2` are in columns A, B, C and D and data starts at row 1.